# using aggregate function in other aggregate function in the SELECT statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having this pretty big aggregate function that I have to use twice in another column, is there a way to write this down without having to write out the first function three times?
So I would like something like this:

```
Select
volumet =
CASE When sum(volume)>200, then 200
     Else sum(volume)
END,
sum(volumet * price) / volumet - price2 * volumet as Profit
FROM tablex
```

Comment: Can you do this in a stored procedure….

Comment: Thx guys, think i can get this to work now!

Comment: If you feel one of the answers was the one that answered your question, check the box next to the answer. Also feel free to upvote any answer you felt was good and helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be what you are looking for based on your original post.

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT
        sum(volumet) AS volumet
    ,   price
    ,   price2
    FROM tablex
    group by price, price2
)
, VolumetValues as
(
    select case when volumet > 200 then 200 else volumet end as volumet
        , price
        , price2
    from CTE
)

SELECT 
    (volumet * price) / volumet - price2 * volumet as Profit
FROM VolumetValues
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
sum(volumet * price) / volumet - price2 * volumet as Profit
FROM
(Select
CASE When sum(volume)>200, then 200
     Else sum(volume)
END as volumet, price, price2
FROM tablex) as tableAux
```

Comment: That isn't going to work. You would be missing a bunch of columns here because you are using your aggregate as the base for your query. You would need to add volumet, price and price2 to the subquery.

Comment: Yes, this is a direction for the complete answer, not the whole answer. Then again, we don't have the complete schema, now, do we? But ok, I'll edit those columns in.